# Is there an easy way in Rapid Miner to find within what range of occurences are the words that are most predictive?

Tags: statistics, analytics, data-analysis, rapidminer, text-analysis

As stated in the question, other than visually looking through the example set fot a number close to 1. and then checking the occurrences of that attribute in the word list, is there an easy way to find the answer to my question? A graph that would show the most predicted words?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use feature selection operators in Rapidminer to find most important and informative words. In this case, you had to transform your text to data frame before applying the feature selection operators.